# How to ensure a single worker picks a task from a queue table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a queue table that is populated with entries to be worked on from workers (there are 4 identical SQL agent jobs).

I would like to ensure that a single worker picks a task and no duplicate work is done, the code I execute is as follows:

```
UPDATE DB.dbo.Queue
SET is_selected = 1
OUTPUT Inserted.ID
INTO @UpdatedRows
FROM (SELECT TOP(1) ID FROM DB.dbo.Queue) q
SELECT ID FROM @UpdatedRows
```

I am considering to use

```
with(tablock, holdlock)
```

or maybe

```
with(tablockx)
```

where do I need to use it, on the SELECT, on the UPDATE or on both?
Is there another option to ensure that a row is picked only by a single worker?

Comment: `UPDATE DB.dbo.Queue WITH(TABLOCKX)`

Comment: Read https://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/

Comment: @DanGuzman I would imagine `UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK` would be all that is necessary, why lock the whole table?

Answer (score 1):

Just do it as one query:

```sql
UPDATE TOP (1) Q
SET is_selected = 1
OUTPUT inserted.ID
FROM Queue Q
WHERE is_selected = 0;
```